# Составление индексов в MySQL

Tags: оптимизация, mysql

Меня интересует вопрос, как правильно выбирать колонки для индексации. Нашел тут ссылку на [статью](http://highload.com.ua/index.php/2009/06/09/как-выбрать-колонки-для-индексирован/) в одном из топиков на хешкоде. Пытался ее осилить несколько раз, и откровенно говоря мало чего понял, что значит "селективные колонки", зачем ставить индексы на те колонки с наименьшим числом строк (это ведь для оптимизации задумано o_O)... Может кто объяснит на пальцах, как все работает, чтобы понял даже дурак, или поделитесь ссылкой на хорошую, подробную статью по этой теме.

Answer (score 3):

Если значения в колонке мало повторяются, то она селективна, т.е. обращение через индекс с конкретным значением даст **мало** строк, в которых это значение присутствует.

Представьте таблицу NAME, YEAR, SEX. YEAR именно *год* рожления. Допустим в таблице 10000 записей. Примерно у 5000 будет SEX=male, примерно у 200 будет совпадать год рождения.

Если сделать индекс по SEX, то он будет бесполезен (даже **вреден**).

Comment: С выражением "селективная колонка" стало более менее понятно, только не пойму зачем в статье на нее ставят индекс. Ведь вроде как наоборот нужно.

И если я правильно понимаю, то в вашем примере оптимально будет добавить индекс только к NAME потому что тут меньше всего встречаются повторы ?

Comment: @webcrack96, ещё можно и к YEAR, но опять же, это зависит от программы. К примеру, если никогда не будут делать выборку по году - то, конечно, такой индекс не нужен.

Comment: Смысл индексирования в том, чтобы выбирать как можно **меньше** лишних строк. Если индекс не селективен, то последовательный просмотр работает быстрее.